# how to print the number when converting from string formatted to int?

Tags: java

```
 String str="1001";
 int I=Integer.parseInt(str);
 str=String.format("%0" + 6 + "d",I);
 System.out.println(str);
 System.out.println(I);
```

output:

```
001001
1001
```

I want to print 001001 instead 1001

Input:

I want string to be modified with leading zeros and then print in integer form

Comment: Do you mean print the integer as `001001`? You can use [`printf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)).

Comment: What is wrong with `String.format`?

Comment: You already have right format in `String.format` method. You can use `System.out.printf("%06d", I);`

Comment: You can't have an integer with leading zeros, because leading zeros in a number make no sense. You need to add the leading zeros when you want to visualize the number and you can do it with `String.format`, as you already did.

Comment: Your output appears to be exactly what you’re asking for.  Consider editing your question and showing us the output you wish to see.

Comment: I am trying to figure out what my sir wanted as a output of Booths algorithm. Suppose I enter the multiplicand as 2 and multiplier as 10 output should be  in same length binary form of multiplicand and multiplier like here 2 should be 0010 and and 10 as 1010 and when multiplied it should be 20 as 00010100  using booths algorithm .If you guys want flowchart for Booths algo please reply .Thankyou for working it out  and sorry for lame question .

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion for this. Check this ....

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class JavaApplication22 {
    public static void main(String args[]){
         String str="1001";
   int I=Integer.parseInt(str);
   str=String.format("%0" + 6 + "d",I);
   DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("000000");
 System.out.println(str);
 System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(I));
    }
}
```

I don't know what your are working on.but if you want leading zero in int you can use this method. Good luck

Comment: I need that string to be modified like suppose M=2 and Q=10 so binary form length should be equal here 2 will be 0010 and 10 as 1010 why extra zeroes in 2 because i have make length equal to the higher decimal number in binary form . I need to adjust zeros by string format and convert it into integer form because i need to perform shifting operation which is needed in my project so shifting is possible only with integer that's why ..Sorry I didn't explain well earlier hope you get it and find solution for this soon . ty